# Visual studio default path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio begins to search for a file not in the project directory, but in a certain folder on the disk. It was found that the error stems from the fact that in VisualStudio 2015 by default for all projects sought in the same folder on disk (C:\WORK_FOLDER), but my colleagues for each project begins with the search for the directory in which the project is located. How change the default folder path in project?